# Pass pattern from variable to grep command

Tags: bash, unix, grep

Hi I need help to know how can we pass the vairble 2015-12-16 08:16: to grep command

```
bash-3.2$ Heartbeat=$(date +%Y-%m-%d$'\t'%H:%M:)                            
bash-3.2$ echo $Heartbeat
2015-12-16 08:16:
```

`bash-3.2$ grep $Heartbeat file.txt` is not working correct, but 
`grep '2015-12-16 08:16:' file.txt` works correctly.

Please help me how can we do this for variable.

Answer (score 4):

```
grep -- "$Heartbeat" file
```

single quotes prevent variable expansion, double quotes allow variable expansion and keep space delimited value together as one argument.

In your case, we also need to add `--` (end of arguments) as your `$Heartbeat` value contains `-` chars, which maybe being interpreted as `grep` options.

IHTH

Comment: No Its not working   Heartbeat=$(date +%Y-%m-%d$'\t'%H:%M:);grep "$Heartbeat" LOOPEUR2015-12-16.log;echo $Heartbeat;2015-12-16 08:41:;grep '2015-12-16 08:41:' LOOPEUR2015-12-16.log;2015-12-16 08:41:01,967 INFO  in.FD_LOOPE_SSGA - <2220 Heartbeat No output when i use"" but we do get output when we pass as '2015-12-16 08:41:'

Comment: Check my updated answer. Also please be more specific when saying it doesn't work. Just no output, OR error messages?

Comment: thank you for specific details. Reading thru them now.

Comment: `--` is only  necessary if `-` were the first character `$Heartbeat`.

Comment: @user4786572 , I think chepner is right. I added `--` as a last shot. I don't know why `grep "$var" file` doesn't return any output when `grep '2015-..' file` does. I'll hope that someone else can help you. (It should work). Good luck.